# How do I load the contents of an rss feed rendered by php?

Tags: file-io, simplexml, php

Wordpress is rendering an RSS feed at http://myurl.com/feed/rss/ but of course there's not actually a file there.  I'm writing a script to read and render the RSS, but loading the "file" as XML fails, because there's not actually a file there. I write:

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('/news/feed/rss/');
```

And I get this error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/news/feed/rss/"
```

Even using file_get_contents gives me this error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(/news/feed/rss/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file isn't there because the url is being redirected, but you're trying to access it as a file. Assuming you have the correct fopen wrappers (and everyone does), try opening the url with simplexml:

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://myurl.com/news/feed/rss/');
```

Comment: This sounds like the best solution, Thanks. Tho the host for this web site says, "URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration". So I'm arguing with that now.

Comment: That's odd, I've never come across a host that has disabled fopen wrappers

Comment: Bah, it's for the best. Go to a WordPress support forum and ask how to get its RSS. There's certainly a function that will return it for you, and it won't incur the performance penalty of handling an extra HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Curl ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php ) for loading external content because you can manipulate with headers etc., it also supports redirects etc.

For example, if mod_security is installed on apache - you wouldn't be able to grab content without passing user-agent header etc., but Curl will definately will help with it.

Comment: You can also set headers with fopen wrappers using stream contexts, negating the need for curl. Besides, the OP doesn't require any headers.

Comment: Original Poster. And I second that comment, you seldom need to use curl. The HTTP wrapper lets you do pretty much anything. http://docs.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php